# How can I make water follow a path?

Tags: physics, fluid-simulation

How can I make water follow a path?

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Have a look at the blender manual [here](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/physics/fluid/types/control.html).

You can also simply use SPH particles and move the emitter :

[image]

the particle settings can be improved to look more like a fluid but that's the basics.

Here's the Blend file : [image]

Comment: Underrated answer. Cool effect, that looks awesome.

Comment: How did you make that @chameleonScales ?

Comment: Well, download the blend file and you'll see.
But not with 2.8. This is an old post.