# How would I go about making a liquid swirl/ similar to the photo?

Tags: fluid-simulation

I'm looking to make a swirl out of yogurt similar to this image. I've tried doing some different simulations but I'm not sure how I could get the liquid to go somewhere specific or to twist it in a particular way. thanks

[image: yogurt reference]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I make water follow a path?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88202/how-can-i-make-water-follow-a-path)

Comment: Look for Gleb's recent splash tutorial on youtube https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=I0Tz1U6A5vI