# Meta Ball Particle System and Fluids interaction

Tags: animation, particles, fluid-simulation

I'm studying the file offered by @ChameleonStyle in [this answer](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/88202/how-can-i-make-water-follow-a-path/104390#104390).

[image]

I do not understand how he did it. When I open the scene, I can see two layers. The first include a particle system linked to a metaBall following a path while a camera targeting an empty turns around it. On the second layer, I can see a fluid system with two cubes, a domain and an inflow.

I am wondering about two things :

1. Where does the metaball and the fluid domain color come from ?
2. Why do they interact?

Thank you for your help...

Comment: The color is just a [matcap](https://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Dev:Ref/Release_Notes/2.66/Usability#Matcap_in_3D_viewport). It seems to me that they don't interact, why do you think that?

Comment: Hi Ty for your answer. When I render the final result, it seems the meatballs particle system mixes with fluids, like air bubbles. Am I wrong ?

Comment: To me there is nothing like that. I think the guy made the two examples independent of each other.

Comment: OK, when I told you I felt dummy ! But How comes the meta balls particles system seem so "fluid" and so smooth ? I tried a hundred times to do the same configuration and every time I do the same thing, my "metaballs rain" comes ugly, full of squary figures (I scale it at the same size in my "Object" configuration under Render Particles System. I even copied it and tried the same system with a cube following my path). I thought there were a link between the two systems... According to you, is his emitter a kind of strange "cube" ? By the way, I do really appreciate you being so patient !

Comment: The quality of the polygonization of the metaballs is controlled through the *View* and *Render* Resolution settings in the metaball properties. The lower the resolution, the better the quality. So tou get smoother result, reduce the values.

Comment: Oh yes, thank you. I reduced to 0.2 each parameter and got a smooth liquid aspect as expected, and put the emission on Volume/Random.